# File `fancyvrb.sty' not found. \RequirePackage

Tags: pdftex, packages, miktex, compiling, fancyvrb

When I try to compile my tex file in TexStudio I get the following error code:

```
File `fancyvrb.sty' not found. \RequirePackage
```

The MiKTeX Console shows that the fancyvrb package is installed and it also compiles with TeXworks.

The console shows the following error log:

```
("E:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\tex\latex\float\float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count173
\float@exts=\toks52
\float@box=\box49
\@float@everytoks=\toks53
\@floatcapt=\box50
)
("E:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\minted\minted.sty"
Package: minted 2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

("E:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fvextra\fvextra.sty"
Package: fvextra 2017/07/08 v1.3.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvr
b

! LaTeX Error: File `fancyvrb.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.27 \RequirePackage
                    {upquote}

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 24721 strings out of 493634
 461525 string characters out of 3141315
 603237 words of memory out of 3000000
 27663 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 62i,0n,56p,1991b,219s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I already tried to reinstall MiKTeX and TexStudio but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Show the log-file of a small failing document.

Comment: Why do you think that this is the part of the log I wanted to see? And show also for comparision the log-file of the working compilation.

Comment: Which log file or part is helpful or where is the log file. In the directory of the tex file is a log file with over 900 lines, which part of it is important?

Comment: I wrote "show the log-file of **small** failing document". Create a test document with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fancyvrb}\begin{document}blub\end{document}`.

Comment: I tried it, now a get following exception, "could not build & view: pdflatex: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".txt could not start". In TeXworks the test document works without any exception.